# Update an element from another controller - account_update_params not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like update an element from another controller.

account_update_params is define in my realtor_controller.

I would like update @realtor from another controller, i use `@realtor.update_attributes(account_update_params)`

Of course, it's not working because account_update_params is not defined in this controller.

How can i "call" account_update_params from another controller ?

Thanks for advance,

F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways of doing this.

Say you have

```
class AccountsContrroller < ApplicationController
   def account_update_params; end 
end

class DifferentAccountsController < ApplicatonController
end
```

My preferred ways from high to low :)

**1 -** Group your controllers under one logical controller and move all your common methods to that and inherit from it  (if it make sense), because that would make your code more maintainable in long run.

Ex:

```
class AccountsHandlingController < ApplicationController
  def account_update_params; end 
end

class AccountsContrroller < AccountsHandlingController
end

class DifferentAccountsController < AccountsHandlingController
end
```

**2)** If your method needs to be used in several places and the method 1 is not applicable, consider creating a module and include it when you want

```
module AccountHandle
  def account_update_params; end
end

class AccountsContrroller < AccountsHandlingController
  include AccountHandle
end

class DifferentAccountsController < AccountsHandlingController
  include AccountHandle
end
```

**3)** Adding it to your application controller if only it's used by almost everywhere, because otherwise your application controller will get messy in no time.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should move method `account_update_params` in application controller.